# Unable to load CSV in neo4j due to periodic commit error

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is the error I am getting while loading a CSV file:

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SemanticError: Executing queries that use
> periodic commit in an open transaction is not possible.

This is the code that I am using:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///bs140513_032310.csv' AS line
WITH line,
  SPLIT(line.customer, "'") AS customerID,
  SPLIT(line.age, "'") AS customerAge,
  SPLIT(line.gender, "'") AS customerGender,
  SPLIT(line.zipcodeOri, "'") AS customerZip,
  SPLIT(line.merchant, "'") AS merchantID,
  SPLIT(line.zipMerchant, "'") AS merchantZip,
  SPLIT(line.category, "'") AS transCategory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of the neo4j browser require that you use the `:auto` browser command to initiate the `USING PERIODIC COMMIT` option.

For example:

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///bs140513_032310.csv' AS line
WITH line,
  SPLIT(line.customer, "'") AS customerID,
  SPLIT(line.age, "'") AS customerAge,
  SPLIT(line.gender, "'") AS customerGender,
  SPLIT(line.zipcodeOri, "'") AS customerZip,
  SPLIT(line.merchant, "'") AS merchantID,
  SPLIT(line.zipMerchant, "'") AS merchantZip,
  SPLIT(line.category, "'") AS transCategory
```

You can get a little more info on `:auto` in the browser by entering this browser command:

```
:help auto
```

Comment: Also, can you help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934702/failed-to-establish-connection-to-1-7687-0-0-reason-99-neo4j

Comment: After loading the data, this is not giving any result: ``` MATCH (c1:customer)-[:MAKE]->(t1:Transaction)-[:WITH]->(b1:merchant)
WITH c1, b1
MERGE (p1:Placeholder {id: b1.id}) ```

Comment: That is a different question, so you should create a new question containing full details, including what your full `LOAD CSV` query looks like. Meanwhile, if my answer worked well for your original question, you should [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.