# Failed to establish connection to ('::1', 7687, 0, 0) (reason 99) Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, google-colaboratory

This is what I am running to use `neo4j` in Google Colab.

```py
from py2neo import Graph

graph = Graph(password="suspects-stop-merchant", bolt_port=32879, http_port=32880)
```

**Here is the image showing my port details:**

[image]

I am getting following error:

```
ServiceUnavailable: Failed to establish connection to ('::1', 7687, 0, 0) (reason 99)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I use in python for most of my queries:

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
from pandas import DataFrame

     def CypherToPandas(Q, database):
        driver=GraphDatabase.driver(Neo4Server, auth=(Neo4UserName,Neo4Pswd),database=database ) 
        with driver.session(database=database) as cyphersession:
            rslt = cyphersession.run(Q)
            df = DataFrame(rslt.data())
            cyphersession.close()
            driver.close()
            return df
```

where Neo4Server = Neo4Server ="bolt://{my server IP at Azure}:7687"

It's very handy that pandas can render the query result directly into a dataframe.

My pip list includes

```
neo4j-driver                4.1.0rc2 
neo4jrestclient             2.1.1 
neobolt                     1.7.17 
pandas                      1.1.0
```

In neo4j v 4.x you need to specify the database.

Answer (score 0):

You probably missing an url parameter, I think this is the correct syntax

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph = Graph("bolt://54.x.x.x:32879", auth=("neo4j", "suspects-stop-merchant"))
```